# Using geom_segment dashed line has odd behavior when using tikz device

Tags: tikz-pgf, knitr

My example is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
<<eg, dev='tikz', size='normalsize', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, sanitize=TRUE>>=
require(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot() + geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 1, xend = 2, yend = 2),
                              linetype= 2)
p1
@
\end{document}
```

Which generates a dashed line (when using other graphics devices). When using tikz, there is a thin black line sitting underneath the dashed line. Any ideas as to how to get rid of this?

Comment: Might be related to https://github.com/yihui/tikzDevice/issues/63 You may ask if Kirill has got any progress on that issue if it is the same one.

Comment: It is indeed the same problem. I also get the correct output looking in my browser. In Sumatra, I see the extra line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out a patch solution for this. Use geom_path to replace the misbehaving geoms. e.g.

```
    p1 + geom_path(data=data.frame(x=c(1, 2),
                          y=c(1, 2)),
          aes(x=x, y=y), linetype=2)
```